# whats is the complement and adjunct in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

I am very confused about the difference between complement and adjunct.... Is there any genius who can identify the complement and adjunct in the below paragraphs?

> Many of us spend an enormous amount of time and energy engaged in work—eight, ten, even twelve hours a day isn't at all uncommon. And whether we work for a giant corporation, a smaller company, or on Wall Street—or, whether we are self-employed,work for the government, or in retail—or for that matter any other industry or business, there's no doubt about it: work can be, and usually is, stressful.
>
> One of the nice by-products of learning not to sweat the small stuff so much is that, eventually, you begin to see more and more of what you have deal with on a daily basis as "small stuff". Whereas before you may have treated practically everything as if it were a really big deal, you may get better at differentiating between the truly significant and that which is far more benign.

Comment: Define your terminology. What do you already understand *complement* and *adjunct* to mean? Where do you think these things (whether you can tell them apart or not) exist in the passage you quoted?

Comment: There are several complements and adjuncts in your sentences. Do you think there is only one of each?